# Javascript - ExtJs - How to add a custom row every nth row in a data grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, split, row

I have a data grid in which each row represent some data about a day of the week.
My store contains at least 7 rows.
What I want to do is split the grid every 7 days with a row that will only contain a custom text/div with the week number.

The final grid should look like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
------------Week1-----------
r1       r1     r1      r1
r2       r2     r2      r2
............................
r7       r7     r7      r7
------------Week2-----------
r1       r1     r1      r1
r2       r2     r2      r2
............................
```

It would be nice to be able to style the Week row, with color, height , etc!

I've looked over Sencha examples and searched for other solutions but I din't find any.
Can this be done (I now it can)? Or can you point me to a possible solution and implementation?

Thank you! I'm using ExtJs 4.0.7

Comment: how do you get the data for the table? do you use a store?

Comment: Yes, i will have a store, which will bind to the columns (col1,col2 ....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have couple options:

- Add extra rows in your store and customize it using row classes
- Use grid grouping plugin if you can identify days belong to one week somehow - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html

Comment: Thank you, @sha. I was actually thinking of implementing it according to your first solution because i think it will look better for the users. Thank your for the idea of creating  extra rows. This will be an editable grid also (editable columns and editable nr of weeks), so the fun have just started, but i think I will handle it:) Marked as answer:)